# Optional Objective-C parameters in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, nullable, optional-parameters

I have an Objective-C method with 2 nullable params:

```
-(void) runInWindow:(NSWindow*)parentWindow answerValidation:(nullable BOOL(^)(void))validator completion:(nullable void(^)(NSModalResponse returnCode))handler;
```

I'd like to call it from Swift like this:

```
dlog.run(in:self.windowForSheet!);
```

But Xcode is not showing that form, only these:

[image: screenshot]

Why can't I call it with only the `in:` parameter?

*Edit: Removed 2nd part.*

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: `nullable` doesn't mean that the method is written in Swift like that: `run(in window: NSWindow anwer: (() -> Bool)? = nil)`. It's the value that is nullable. It's not an optiional parameter.

Comment: The completion handlers are nullable, but mandatory. Objective C doesn't have a way to specify default arguments, so you need to pass `nil` explicitly

Comment: In Objective-C, to replicate that behavior, we need to add `-(void) runInWindow:(NSWindow*)parentWindow { [self runInWindow:parentWindow answerValidation: nil]; }` (I've skipped the second parameter, for clarity)

Comment: Ah, so the fact that Xcode gives me a code completion that shows an optional completion: handler is because it's named "completion:" and not because it's nullable. I think that jibes with Apple's doc about this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/calling-objective-c-apis-asynchronously